# How to create a reusable function for LINQ where clause with extra param

Tags: c#, linq

I want to do something like this:

```
const string user = "Jim";
var emps = employees.Where(FilterEmployees(user));

Func<Employee, string, bool> FilterEmployeesType = FilterEmployees;
static bool FilterEmployees(Employee e, string username)
{
    return e.Username.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper() && !e.Deleted;
}
```

This works if the signature of the delegate contains only *Employee*. How can I also pass in another value?

Just to clarify, this works for me:

```
var emps = employees.Where(e => !e.Deleted);
```

or, after converting to call a delegate/function:

```
var emps = employees.Where(FilterEmployees);

Func<Employee, bool> FilterEmployeesType = FilterEmployees;
static bool FilterEmployees(Employee e)
{
    return !e.Deleted;
}
```

However, I also want to pass an additional parameter into the function so that it can handle this situation:

```
const string user = "Jim";
var emps = employees.Where(e => e.Username.ToUpper() == user.ToUpper() && !e.Deleted);
```

How do I get the variable *user* into the function?

Comment: not sure I understand what you like to do correctly, but wouldn't [Predicate<Employees>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) be what you need?

Comment: Let me try and clarify in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let the function return a predicate, instead of using it as a predicate directly, you can pass any parameter passed in its body:

```
static Func<Employee,bool> FilterEmployees(string username)
{
    return e => e.Username.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper() && !e.Deleted; //small sidenote: performance wise this could be tweaked, by at the least putting `username = username.ToUpper()` outside the lambda instead having it done on each call
}
```

With the above you can use your example `var emps = employees.Where(FilterEmployees(user));`

---

Also a small addition (might not be what you need, but for the sake of mentioning it): an alternative is to have the `Filter` method do the actual filtering (acting as a `where`), by having it return the altered enumerable (and for ease of use, declaring it as an extension method):

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> FilterEmployees(this IEnumerable<Employee> employees, string username)
{
    return employees.Where(e => e.Username.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper() && !e.Deleted);
}
```

If the above is put inside an accessible static class, the call can be written as: `var emps = employees.FilterEmployees(user);`

Comment: Ooh! I was so close! Perfect. Thanks!